# how can i call total calculated in procedure in php

Tags: php, oracle, stored-procedures

i have 2 tables involved to create this stored procedure.

```
CREATE TABLE CAGE(
cageNo VARCHAR2(15) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
cageType VARCHAR2(50),
description VARCHAR2(50),
price FLOAT,
status VARCHAR2 (50));


CREATE TABLE STAYRECORD(
stayRecID VARCHAR2(15) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
checkInDate DATE,
checkOutDate DATE,
cageNo VARCHAR2(15) REFERENCES CAGE(cageNo),
animalID VARCHAR2(15) REFERENCES ANIMAL(animalID));
```

i want to create a procedure that can calculate the total price based on the checkindate and checkoutdate from table stayrecord and to display the total without having to store the total in the database.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calcTotal
(p_checkInDate IN STAYRECORD.checkInDate%TYPE,
p_checkOutDate IN STAYRECORD.checkOutDate%TYPE,
p_stayRecID IN STAYRECORD.stayRecID%TYPE,
p_cageNo  IN STAYRECORD.cageNo%TYPE,
p_cageNoC  IN CAGE.cageNo%TYPE)

IS
TOTAL NUMBER;

BEGIN

TOTAL := 'select (to_date(checkOutDate) - to_date(checkInDate))*c.price'||  
      'from STAYRECORD r, CAGE c'||
      'where r.cageNo = c.CAGENO AND r.STAYRECID = p_stayRecID';
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TOTAL);

END;
/
```

i have created procedure as shown above to calculate total price based on the date inserted by users. how do i retrieve the total calculated in the php?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to output your result. If you use a procedure, then it should have an `OUT` parameter with your result.

Add `p_total OUT number` parameter to your procedure definition.

Your procedure should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calcTotal
  (p_checkInDate IN STAYRECORD.checkInDate%TYPE,
  p_checkOutDate IN STAYRECORD.checkOutDate%TYPE,
  p_stayRecID IN STAYRECORD.stayRecID%TYPE,
  p_cageNo  IN STAYRECORD.cageNo%TYPE,
  p_cageNoC  IN CAGE.cageNo%TYPE,
  p_total OUT number)

IS
BEGIN

  p_total := 'select (to_date(checkOutDate) - to_date(checkInDate))*c.price'||  
    'from STAYRECORD r, CAGE c'||
    'where r.cageNo = c.CAGENO AND r.STAYRECID = p_stayRecID';
  END;
/
```

In PHP you can use the code below:

```
<?php 
  $conn = oci_connect('your_conn_name', 'your_conn_password', 'localhost/XE');
  if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e('message'), ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
  }

  $query = "begin 
               calcTotal(:check_in_date, 
                         :check_out_date, 
                         :stayRecId, 
                         :cage_no, 
                         :cageNoC, 
                         :total_out); 
            end;";

  $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);

  $check_in =     /* put your data type here */;
  $check_out =    /* put your data type here */; 
  $stay_rec_id =  /* put your data type here */;
  $cage_no =      /* put your data type here */;
  $cage_noc =     /* put your data type here */;

  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":check_in_date",  $check_in);
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":check_out_date", $check_out);
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":stayRecId",      $stay_rec_id);
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":cage_no",        $cage_no);
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":cageNoC",        $cage_noc);
  oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":total_out",      $total_result);

  oci_execute($stid);

  echo $total_result;
?>`
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a function which returns the total?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calcTotal
    (p_checkInDate IN STAYRECORD.checkInDate%TYPE,
    p_checkOutDate IN STAYRECORD.checkOutDate%TYPE,
    p_stayRecID IN STAYRECORD.stayRecID%TYPE,
    p_cageNo  IN STAYRECORD.cageNo%TYPE,
    p_cageNoC  IN CAGE.cageNo%TYPE)
    return number
IS
    TOTAL NUMBER;
BEGIN

    select (checkOutDate - checkInDate))*c.price
    into total
    from STAYRECORD r, CAGE c
    where r.cageNo = c.CAGENO 
    AND r.STAYRECID = p_stayRecID;

    return TOTAL;

END;
/
```

The procedure had a lot of parameters which your query didn't use. I have left them in, but if they are redundant you should remove them from the program's signature.